# Prometheus remote_write, external_labels and "local labels"

Tags: prometheus

I configured 2 kubernetes cluster with 2 instances of prometheus each.
Every prometheus instance is collecting metrics on its own cluster.

Then I decided to use the first prometheus instance installed in the first k8s cluster as collector of all the metrics, so that I could monitor everything from a single instance.

I configured the remote write and the external labels

```
external_labels:
  cluster: "prom-aux-01"
...
remote_write:
  - url: http://prom-primary:9090/api/v1/write
    remote_timeout: 30s
```

Everything is working fine. Now I'm able to query data from my "primary" instance and from my "prom-aux-01" instance.

**BUT!!! I would like to add the label `cluster: "primary"` on all the metrics collected by the primary instance. I would like to configure it in an easy and automatic way. Similar to what I can do with the `external_labels` setting.**

How can I do it?